# How can I check if an ArrayList<String> contains any elements from an array of Strings?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity, arraylist

Within Android, I'd like to perform an if statement to check whether an ArrayList contains **any element from an array of Strings**? 
e.g.

Check whether any of the elements from *singingGroup* are also containined in *Winners[]*

```
String Winners[] = {"Jennifer", "Steven", "Peter", "Parker"};

ArrayList<String> singingGroup  = new ArrayList<String>();

singingGroup.add("Patrick");

singingGroup.add("Jane");

singingGroup.add("Joe");

singingGroup.add("Susan");

singingGroup.add("Amy");
```

**How can I do this?** *as I know how to check if one item is contained as in another array as below*. **But not if any from one, exist in another**.

```
if (Arrays.asList(Winners).contains(singingGroup)) {
```

Comment: Are you trying to prevent duplicates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
Collections.disjoint(singingGroup, Arrays.asList(Winners));
```

to test, is the 2 arguments have no common element(s) in common. (see also [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection%3C?%3E,%20java.util.Collection%3C?%3E%29))

The negation of the result seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: yes.Collections.disjoint returns true if the two specified collections have no elements in common.

Answer (score 2):

Collections.disjoint is one way to archive this but You can also use **retainAll()** method.

> Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this list all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection.

### Case I :elements from singingGroup are not containined in Winners[]

```
String Winners[] = {"Jennifer", "Steven", "Peter", "Parker"};
ArrayList<String> singingGroup  = new ArrayList<String>();

singingGroup.add("Patrick");
singingGroup.add("Jane");
singingGroup.add("Joe");
singingGroup.add("Susan");
singingGroup.add("Amy");

List<String> WinnerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Winners));
WinnerList.retainAll(singingGroup);
System.out.println("retainList = " + WinnerList);
```

Output

```
list1 = []
```

### Case II:elements from singingGroup are also containined in Winners[]

```
String Winners[] = {"Jennifer", "Steven", "Peter", "Parker"};
ArrayList<String> singingGroup  = new ArrayList<String>();

singingGroup.add("Steven");
singingGroup.add("Jane");
singingGroup.add("Joe");
singingGroup.add("Susan");
singingGroup.add("Jennifer");

List<String> WinnerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Winners));
WinnerList.retainAll(singingGroup);
System.out.println("retainList = " + WinnerList);
```

Output

```
retainList = [Jennifer, Steven]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also check like this:

```
String Winners[] = {"Jennifer", "Patrick", "Peter", "Parker"};

        ArrayList<String> singingGroup  = new ArrayList<String>();

        singingGroup.add("Patrick");

        singingGroup.add("Jane");

        singingGroup.add("Joe");

        singingGroup.add("Susan");

        singingGroup.add("Amy");

        for(int i=0; i< Winners.length;i++)
        {
            if(singingGroup.contains(Winners[i]))
            {
                System.out.println("duplicate");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) class provided by Apache Commons.

Using the *intersection* method (useful if you want to do something with the common elements):

```
Collection<String> intersection = CollectionUtils.intersection(singingGroup, Arrays.asList(Winners));

if (intersection.size() > 0){

    // At least one element contained in the intersection
}
```

Or, using the *containsAny* method:

```
if (CollectionUtils.containsAny(singingGroup, Arrays.asList(Winners))){

    // True if at least one common element exists in both lists  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//for loop would be perfect to check if element i = element i

int i =0;
int loopCount = 0;
while(loopCount < Winners.lenght)
{
  for(int i =0; i < singingGroup.length; i++)
  {
    if(Winners[loopCount] == singingGroup[i])
    {
    System.out.println(Winners[loopCount] + "is apart of the winners");
    }//end of comparing if

    if(i == singing.Group.length)
    { 
    loopCount ++;
    } //end of i == singingGroup

  }//end of for loop

}//end of while  loop
```

This is not the most optimal code but if you need it in a hurry this will work